# Creating a RX Observable without calling onComplete is it Valid?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am not expert in Rx sorry if it is trivial question so.I am doing a polling operation which I have to wait for updates and I created Rx Observable for that; however, I never call onComplete. but in onDestroy I unsubscribe. please take a look on the below code.

```
@Reusable
class PollingExample @Inject constructor() {
    var itemObservable: Observable<List<Item>>
        private set
    private lateinit var itemObservableEmitter: WeakReference<ObservableEmitter<List<Item>>>

    init {
        itemObservable = Observable.create { e -> itemObservableEmitter = WeakReference(e) }
    }

    fun submitData(items: List<Item>) {
        itemObservableEmitter.get()?.onNext(items)
    }
}
```

is it Valid to do something like that

Comment: Yes. They are called infinite sources.

Comment: I found RX Relay will fit better, but thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search I think as long as I do not want to call `onError()` or `onComplete()` it is better to use this library https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay which guarantee that everything will continue working without the worry of accidentally triggering a terminal state